Android Studio: Gradle demoted library version from xx.xx to yy.yy
Suddenly -and for an unknown reason for me- I've started to receive a "Gradle demoted library version from xx.xx to yy.yy" warning when trying to update packages from "Project Structure" > Suggestions.
After years working with Android and Kotlin it's the first time I see this warning, so I don't know what to do to update my packages.
Two weird things:

It's giving this warning not for just one specific package, but for all.
I wasn't able to find any information / references about this warning anywhere on the net, but at the link I'm pasting below, which is not helpful for me.

I need to clearly understand what this error means, I mean, what it happens, and mostly why it happens for all the packages.
I've already upgraded my targetSdk to 35 with the SDK upgrade assistant (just in case) to no avail.
My Android Studio is "Koala" 2024.1.2
What should I try next to update my packages to latest versions without this warning?

What to do when seeing Gradle demoted library version

When different dependencies in the project try to use different versions of the same library, to ensure compatibility gradle will demote to the lowest required version
Open terminal & run
./gradlew :app:dependencies

and check conflicts

Thanks for your reply @user27894462, I did it, but don't know how to analyze the results, and they're to long to paste them here (have to say it's a multi-module app). So I'm stuck, and the most weird thing is this never happened to me before, why now and suddenly?

@DiegoPerez Copy the output to a text editor and search "com.google.dagger:hilt-android" and try to find out if "2.51.1" is mentioned. If it is, some dependency is trying to use 2.51.1 and causing a conflict. Check if there's an update for that dependency
You can try to put this in your gradle and force it to use 2.52. Compatibility issues may arise. Give it a try. //////
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
force 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.52'
}
}

Thanks again @user27894462. I've done the search and com.google.dagger:hilt-android appears everywhere, and even the results are shown in a nice tree format, it's quite difficult to locate the parent of every occurrence. I think for the moment I'll give up.

The weird thing is that after years developing for Android this has never happened to me, and now it suddenly happens for all libraries. BTW, I don't want to force anything, if it won't go "naturally", I prefer to keep it like it is.
